# exec ant replace a value in a .m file

Tags: file, ant, replace, exec

how to write an exec task in ant to replace two values in .m file.
Because I want to replace the version number in iphone app, including my build number which i build using hudson, i remotely access the macos and get the app to be copied on to my windows
system, so i generated the build using ant exec tasks, but now i want to replace my build number into the concern file before compiling,
so how can i use exec task to replace certain values in a file.
I know propertyfile task which replaces the value in a property file, but it doesn't work for
this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *template* file, you can use the [`<copy>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task with a nested [`<filterset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) to replace certain values. If not, you can still use [`<copy>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html), this time with a nested filter chain containing a [`<replaceregex>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex) [token filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#tokenfilter). If you want to edit in place, you can [move](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) the newly created file to the old location afterwards.

The use of [`<exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) is almost certainly a bad idea for your application, as it would make your build rely on external applications which usually are not available on all platforms, thus breaking portability of your build.

Comment: I don't want to use copy task, I want to execute my build on mac, thats the reason I want to use exec.

Comment: @user1330847, what do you mean by “execute my build”? To me, executing a build means calling ant and letting it do what needs to be done. And as long as a given task gets the job done, why should I want to use another task? I have the feeling there is some deep misunderstanding here, but I can't pinpoint it yet.